# mongodb error: positional operator did not find the match needed from the query

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I used Spring Boot rest api with MongoDB.
In PUT Method, for existing scoreID, I try update the filed score and also update this filed in the history.
but when execute my program in Postman, I have this error in the Postman:

```
"status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.' on server localhost:27017
```

And the error in the console:

```
Command failed with error 2 (BadValue): 'The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.", "code": 2, "codeName": "BadValue"}
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.ProtocolHelper.getCommandFailureException(ProtocolHelper.java:175) ~[mongo-java-driver-3.11.2.jar:na]
```

The PUT Method:

```
    //Update Score By ID
    @PutMapping("/{scoreid}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateScoreByID(
            @PathVariable("scoreid")String scoreid,
            @RequestBody @Valid Score score){
        Score findScore =srepo.findByScoreid(score.getScoreid()); 
        if(findScore == null)
            return ResponseEntity.status(404).
                    body("There is not Score with indicated ScoreID!");
        else {
            Query query = new Query();
            query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("scoreid").is(score.getScoreid()));
            Update update = new Update();
            update.set("score", score.getScore());
            mongoTemplate.findAndModify(query, new Update().set("history.$.score", score.getScore()), Score.class);
            mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, Score.class);
            //(query, new Update().set("score", score.getScore()), Score.class);                

            //(query, new Update().set("history.$.score", score.getScore()),Score.class);
            return ResponseEntity.status(200).body("Updated!");

    }
}
```

And the Score Class:

```
 @Document(collection = "score")
public class Score {
    @Id
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String scoreid;
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private Long score;
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String player;
    @NotBlank
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private String gamecode;
    @JsonView(Views.class)
    private Date date;
    private List<History> history;
```

could you help me what is my mistake?!

Comment: As `history` is a list, assuming something like : `[{score: 1},{score: 2}]` then in your `query` you need to have this filter `history.score : score.getScore()` that's when positional operator `$` would know which object of `history` array needs to be updated !

Comment: thank you, before I wrote like this in mongoTemplate, in the query, but i had an error exactly for history.score and after that i used .$.score. But nothing change